# Need help to Create new Google Spreadsheet

Tags: google-docs, google-sheets, google-sheets-api

I want to creating a new Spreadsheet in my http://docs.google.com account, using the C#. It is possible to create a new spreadsheet.Please show some syntax or valuable information that help me to create spreadsheet.

Comment: Have you checked the google api documentation for this? Just Google "google spreadsheet api" for it :)

Comment: jamie thanks for reply,by using programming language ,i just want to know is it possible to create spreadsheet not worksheet.if it's possible then how .i follow this url ,need help to create spreadsheet programmatically. https://developers.google.com/google-apps/spreadsheets/

Answer (score 2):

You have to use the Documents List API to create a new spreadsheet. The documentation has complete C# samples:

https://developers.google.com/google-apps/documents-list/#creating_or_uploading_spreadsheets